# Exception in aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, exception, c++14, aggregate, valgrind

In C++14 (gcc 6.3) I have the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

struct A
{
    int a1;
    int a2;
};

struct B
{
    int b1;
    std::shared_ptr< std::vector<A> > Alist;        
};

struct C
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
    std::shared_ptr< std::vector<A> > Alist;        
};    

std::shared_ptr< std::vector<A> > makeListA()
{
    std::vector<A> toto = {{0,1}, {2,3}};
    return std::make_shared< std::vector<A> >(toto);
}

std::shared_ptr< std::vector<A> > makeListAWithException()
{
    throw std::out_of_range("My exception");
}

std::shared_ptr<B> makeB()
{
    return std::make_shared<B>(B{0, makeListA()});
}

main()
{
    std::make_unique<C>(C{makeB(),makeListAWithException()});
}
```

When running valgrind i have a memory leak : it looks like the objects created by "makeB()" function were not freed. I had this problem only when using aggregate initialization with curly braces.

When I define an explicit constructor on each class (A, B and C), I don't have this issue.

What am I doing wrong ?

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [gcc bug 66139](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66139). Here is a short reproduction, courtesy of [Andrzej](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/a-serious-bug-in-gcc/) (with a more thorough description available in the blog post):

> ```
> #include <cstdio>
> #include <stdexcept>
>
> struct Resource
> {
>   explicit Resource(int) { std::puts("create"); }
>   Resource(Resource const&) { std::puts("create"); }
>   ~Resource() { std::puts("destroy"); }
> };
>
> Resource make_1() { return Resource(1); }
> Resource make_2() { throw std::runtime_error("failed"); }
>
> struct User 
> {
>   Resource r1;
>   Resource r2;
> };
>
> void process (User) {}
>
> int main()
> {
>   try {
>     process({make_1(), make_2()});
>   }
>   catch (...) {}
> }
> ```

This prints:

```
create
```

It should print (as clang, correctly, does):

```
create
destroy
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have associated `try`/`catch` so your program terminate.

stack unwinding is not required in that case.

Following should solve your possible leak.

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::make_unique<C>(C{makeB(), makeListAWithException()});
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Valgrind output changes from `possibly lost: 192 bytes in 1 blocks` (from `makeListAWithException()`) to `definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks` / `indirectly lost: 56 bytes in 2 blocks` (from `makeB()`)...

Comment: Even with try catch i have the same issue

Comment: GCC seems bugged. With Clang, the `try-catch` results in no leaks. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d475ffd90c6feba8

Comment: Thank you for your response but i want to throw an exception in my program. The code that i wrote is just an example to illustrate the issue, in the real code i have many nested constructors and the exception may occurs from one or more of them.

Comment: Tip: a [function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) looks pretty nice here.

Comment: @Lateef - Yes, I tried without a try-catch in Clang. The stack isn't unwound. As is to be expected, since it's allowed (that isn't a bug). If you want `main` to unwind the stack with 100% certainty, you need to put in place a handler. See Quentin's link for an "all encompassing" quick fix.

Comment: So, if I understand, i have to define a constructor to my class "C"  to use function-try-block?

Answer (score 0):

if you change to like below, i think the problem is fixed

```
std::make_unique<C>(C{makeB(),makeListAWithException()});
```

to

```
auto b = makeB();
std::make_unique<C>(C{b,makeListAWithException()});
```

Comment: when exception occurred, it just like do not call descontruct if this struct has no descontruct methord

Comment: Thank you for your response. The code that i wrote is just an example to illustrate the issue, in the real code i have many nested constructors and the exception may occurs from one or more of them. So, i can't do an "auto" to each object constructed

Comment: i have checked and i have the same issue